# Word - Can you tell if the user Cancels a save

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, office-2007

I've been searching for an answer to this but can find anything on it.

In Word, when the user closes a document they are prompted with the "save", Cancel Save", "Cancel" dialog.

Is there a way to tell which one of those buttons the user clicked on?

I know the even DocumentBeforeSave is sent out, But I can't find a way to tell which button the user actually clicked on.

I need to know in particular if the user clicked the "Cancel Save"

Note: using c#; 2007 dll's

Comment: I think this is one of those icky areas in the Office Object Model - if a Save /didn't happen/ after a BeforeSave then it was cancelled or otherwise aborted.

Comment: See http://davecra.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/word-aftersave-event/ - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that cancel save and cancel are the same thing. When a user saves a document, you will see a DocumentSave.